# VK API (Android), где найти класс VKApi

Tags: android, api, вконтакте

Начиная с версии 2.0 com.vk:androidsdk не содержит в себе класса VKApi. Он вынесен в отдельную библиотеку? Если да, то как её найти?

P.S аналогичных методов VKApi в com.vk:androidsdk 2.x.x не нашёл

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно скачать старую версию библиотеки https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-android-sdk/releases/tag/1.6.7
Там в корне есть файл readme в нём инструкция на английском языке как подключать.